# Addition of textarea (int) values

Tags: jquery

I'm facing a little problem with my jQuery / Javascript code.

I have several values on a page, like :

```
checkbox EXAMPLE EXAMPLE 150
checkbox EXAMPLE EXAMPLE 300
checkbox EXAMPLE EXAMPLE 300
```

I have this little code, which basically just add the numerical values (150, 300, 300) to an array, and then, sum the array in the "total" variable. (Well, at least this is what I'm trying to do...)

Here's the code :

```
 $('.pack_check').click(function() {
        var cout = [];
        total = 0;
        $('#services_pack input:checked').each(function() {
            cout.push(this.cout);
            $.each(cout,function() {
                total += parseInt(this);
                });
            });
        });
    });
```

My problem is, that when I click on my first checkbox, it's ok, total = 150
But, if I click on the second checkbox, total = (150 + 150 + 300) which is a bit annoying...

Anyone ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: What is `this.cout` supposed to point to? What's the relationship between the textareas and the checkboxes? Do you even need an array if you simply want to get the sum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is likely that you've got a nested loop adding to your total. So for every checked checkbox you first add its `.cout` to the array, and then you add every element in the array to the total again. Also you have too many closing `});`. Try this:

```
$('.pack_check').click(function() {
    var cout = [];
    total = 0;
    $('#services_pack input:checked').each(function() {
        cout.push(this.cout);
    });
    $.each(cout,function() {
        total += parseInt(this, 10);
    });
    // do something with total
});
```

Or if you just need the total eliminate the `cout` array:

```
$('.pack_check').click(function() {
    var total = 0;
    $('#services_pack input:checked').each(function() {
        total += parseInt(this.cout, 10);
    });
    // use total here
});
```

Note that `parseInt()` takes a second parameter to specify the radix, so if you want to work in base 10: `parseInt(stringToParse,10)` - avoids problems if the string starts with a leading `0` or leading `0x`, which would otherwise be interpreted as base 8 and base 16 (respectively).

Having said that, I recommend the unary plus operator to convert a string to a number:

```
total += +this;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have global 'total' which is changed only by the value of checked/unchecked checkbox count.

```
var total = 0;

$('.pack_check').click(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    total += parseInt(this_count);
  } else {
    total -= parseInt(this_count);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks ! Worked like a charm ! :)

Answer (score 0):

split your `.each()` functions, what's happening is your code is adding 150 to cout then to total, then on the second pass it again adds 150 and 300 to the current total, thus the 150 + 150 +300. it should be the following:

```
$('.pack_check').click(function() {
    //adds to array
    var cout = [];
    $('#services_pack input:checked').each(function() {
        cout.push(this.cout);
        });

    //totals all within the array
    total = 0;
    $.each(cout,function() {
         total += parseInt(this);
        });
    }); // end of click function
```

Comment: Worked great too, and seems totally logical now...

Thanks ! :)